# How can I select a column from an SQlite table?

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I use this query in my android database:

```
  public String getauthWithid() {
    String query = new String( "select login from table_inscri where ID = 1" );
    Cursor result = bdd.rawQuery( query, null );
    return result.toString();}
```

But when I call this method it returns `android.database.sqlite.SQliteCursor@`

So how can I select the column when the id=1?

Comment: Cursor is all you need. Read the docs please: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Comment: How can i read the culumn where the cursor point ?*

Answer (score 2):

Edit: 
As Graham has pointed out you will have to close cursor. So use below code

```
result.moveToFirst();
String auth = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
result.close();
return auth;
```

Comment: Note also that the cursor should be closed before returning from the function.

Comment: `Cursor.getString(int)` takes the column index, not name. You want to use `getColumnIndexOrThrow()` in there too, or else just use `0` since it's such a simple query.

Comment: Actually checking the return value from `result.moveToFirst()` before calling `result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("login"))` willy-nilly would also be wise.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way of doing it. To prevent errors.

```
public String getauthWithid() {
   String query = new String( "select login from table_inscri where ID = 1" );
   Cursor result = bdd.rawQuery( query, null );

   String returnString = ""; // Your default if none is found

  if(result.moveToFirst())
  {
    returnString = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("login"));
  }
  result.close();

  return returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this should get the data from the column of the data set.

```
if (result != false) 
{
    result.moveToFirst(); // moves the cursor to the first record        
    do 
    {
        result.getString(0); // gets the data in that record
        // process string here 
        // - such as add to an arrayList and then return the list after the loop
    } 
    while (result.moveToNext()); 
    // return list here
}
```

Comment: `if (c != null)` ... what is `c`? Did you mean `result`? It can't be `null`, so it's a pointless check.

Comment: yes sorry, just copied it from my own code.
what if the search returns nothing in the database? 

moveToFirst would result in an error then wouldn't it?

Comment: No results will cause `moveToFirst()` to return `false`. An error will result in an exception being thrown. There are no circumstances in which the query can return a `null` cursor.

Answer (score -1):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select login from table_inscri where ID='" + 1
            + "'", null);
```

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

Just go into your sqlite shell:

```
$ sqlite3 path/to/db.sqlite3
```

Once in it, just hit  `sqlite> .schema`

and you will get everything.

Comment: How does this answer the question?